# ¿Como puedo actualizar un campo de una tabla con distintos buttons y cada uno actualiza un campo de la misma tabla en php?

Tags: php, sql

```
if(isset($_POST['nombre_admin']) && isset($_POST['entrada'])){
    $nombre_admin=MysqlQuery::RequestPost('nombre_admin');
    $entrada=date("d/m/y H:i:s");       

   MysqlQuery::Guardar("fichaje", "nombre_admin, entrada","'$nombre_admin', '$entrada'")

if(isset($_POST['nombre_admin']) && isset($_POST['salida'])){


$sql=Mysql::consulta("SELECT * FROM fichaje WHERE nombre_admin= '$nombre_admin'");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>=1){
            MysqlQuery::Actualizar("fichaje", "salida='$salida'", "nombre_admin='$nombre_admin'")



 <form role="form" action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $reg1['nombre_admin'];?> name="nombre_admin" required="">
        <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Entrada</button></center>
      </form>
```

Quiero crear un sistema de fichaje, el primer button será insertar dos campos en una tabla (nombre admin y entrada) en el segundo button la salida y otros dos para la comida, si se como poner el de salida los otros dos seran igual.

Comment: Corrige el post, y detalla de mejor manera la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes poner múltiples formularios con un valor `hidden` que le indica a PHP qué es lo que debe actualizar.

Lo siguiente es solo un ejemplo conceptual. Solo se enviarán las variables del formulario correspondiente al `submit` presionado, por lo tanto los `name` pueden estar repetidos en distintos `form`.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="act_entrada">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="153">
    <input type="text" name="campo1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="campo2" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Actualizar Entrada">
</form>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="act_salida">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="153">
    <input type="text" name="campo1" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Actualizar Salida">
</form>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="act_comida">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="153">
    ... <!-- campos para actualizar -->
    <input type="submit" value="Actualizar Comida">
</form>
```

Y en el PHP se hace la lógica. Como dije anteriormente, esto es solo un concepto. Aquí hay potenciales problemas de seguridad como vulnerabilidad a inyección SQL y quién sabe qué más.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    if($action == 'act_entrada') {
        $data1 = $_POST['campo1'];
        $data2 = $_POST['campo2'];
        $query = "UPDATE tu_tabla SET col1='$data1', col2='$data2' WHERE id=$user_id";
        // ...
    } elseif($action == 'act_salida') {
        $data1 = $_POST['campo1'];
        $query = "UPDATE tu_tabla SET col3='$data1' WHERE id=$user_id";
        // ...
    } elseif($action == 'act_comida') {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias probare a ver, como esto será algo interno no "debería" haber problema